# Badly coded Adsense ads are killing my site's performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, ads, adsense

This is my site: www.gpstudios.com
I've had this problem for the best part of 3 months now.
Since doing a major update in March, some recurring ads make the site unusable.
I've requested help on this issue multiple times but nobody has yet suggested a solution.
I know it's the ads causing this lag, if I delete them in Chrome's developer tools or isolate them, it's very clear that they're the culprit.
You'll notice some ads follow the page. I've tried disabling this script (and every other running script) and this doesn't help.
Also, I've been told it's Flash's fault (my site mostly features Flash games) but it clearly isn't, some pages don't have any Flash objects and yet the problem still persists just as badly.

I just don't understand it, Google have burdened me with some horrible ads (at least on my end) that are basically malicious in that they destroy functionality of any page they display on.
I am mystified why I can't find other people with a similar problem, as some specific recurring ads are so badly broken that a single one can ruin performance for the entire page.

With the Google Publisher Toolbar I've block and reported the bad ones, but they come back within a week or so.
Some ads spew out hundreds of warnings and errors, some ads are just horribly inefficient animated canvases with loads of moving elements.

What else can I do to prevent/fix these ads besides using a different ad service?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might also be a good place to post this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other option then testing and blocking the ads.

You can try to turn of Flash and moving ads and keep Text and image on. Also turn off expandable ads. They are really slowing things down.
If the problem still persists it is your website.

Try working on your website speed, this will help. A great tool is Pagespeed insights from Google.